# ProgressBar not updating correctly after animation

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a Layout with a ProgressBar(actually it is a SeekBar but the same problem happens with the ProgressBar). It works fine until I start animating the whole Layout, translating it down. During the animation the ProgressBar continues to work as expected, but when the animation is finished(and I freeze the Layout at the final position of the animation using Animation.setFillAfter(true)), the ProgressBar stops updating correctly, instead just a small line on the top of the bar keeps updating while the bottom part of the progressBar stays frozen(its a horizontal progressBar).

Some code:
The Layout with the ProgressBar:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/video_buttons"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|left">   
<SeekBar
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:id="@+id/progressbar_Horizontal"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:max="100"
/>
```

Here is where I define the Animation:

```
Animation a = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.translate_down);
a.setFillAfter(true);
```

Here is where I start the animation on the whole Layout:

```
View vv = p.findViewById(R.id.video_buttons);
vv.startAnimation(anim);
```

Comment: There's not enough code. You should post a complete test case.

Answer (score 0):

My first thought is that you may be unintentionally using the "android:secondaryProgress" property.

Other than this, if you're running this in a seperate thread, make sure you're using the following:

```
activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() //
            {
                public void run() //
                {
                    int newProgressVal = Integer
                            .parseInt((String) syncProgressNumber.getText()) + 1;
                    syncProgress.incrementProgressBy(1);
                    syncProgressNumber.setText(String
                            .valueOf(newProgressVal));
                }
            });
```

The UI thread is not threadsafe, so you can't update the UI from other threads.

Hope this helps!